# Algorithm to shorten city names to human readable codes

Tags: string, algorithm, url, geolocation

I am using the region and city in urls for this project. Now many regions and cities might have very long names while also combinations of shortened region/city information might lead to ambiguity.

Is there an easy approach to automatically shorten words in a way so they still make sense and are readable but are shortened without just cutting the end of?

Like turning Bremerhaven into Brmhvn or New Haven, Connecticut to NewHvn-Cnctct?

Comment: remove all the vowels. we don't need them!

Comment: There are only 50 states, so you can use a lookup table to map them to their two character representations (e.g. New York -> NY, Connecticut -> CT)

Comment: The problem here is what do you call "make sense". In polish strzlzwsk may make sense, but not in English. And it is not the language differences. You need to define your criteria better.

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: There are 50 States in the USA. The USA, as big as it may seem, is not the whole world ;D

Comment: @izomorphius: Good point. I may be able to ignore that problem for now and use Mitch Wheats approach. But i'll have to look into it for the future

Comment: @AndreschSerj Ah, sorry - I thought you were doing US-only (Bremerhaven sounds like it could be in the US!) I'm not even American myself - I'm British :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2797245 cities in the list of world cities freely available from http://www.maxmind.com/app/worldcities

I would design the URL pattern similar to

```
{Country TLD}/{Abbreviation for state, province or prefecture}/{Trim of county or district}/{Trim of city}
```

Some examples,

- www.example.com/US/NY/-/NewYork
- www.example.com/US/NY/*Westcheste*/MtVernon ([Mount Vernon in Westchester County, New York](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Vernon,_New_York)) 
  *- county trimmed to 10 first characters. Also common words in city names abbreviated*
- www.example.com/DE/Bavaria/Munich
- www.example.com/JP/Tohoku/Miyagi/Sendai ([Sendai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sendai,_Miyagi))

For the region, you may want to consider using the [ISO 3166 code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166). So, the above examples for Munich and Sendai would look like

- www.example.com/JP/Tohoku/*JP-04*/Sendai
- www.example.com/DE/*DE-BY*/Munich

Other leads

- [HASC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_administrative_subdivision_codes) (Hierarchical administrative subdivision codes) which is used to
  represent names of country subdivisions, such as states, province,
  regions.
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2:US
- http://www.statoids.com/uus.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: Just: Wow! Exactly what i was looking for. You are my favorite person of the day! Thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 2):

If you want the shorter version to make sense for humans I think this is incredibly complex as its not very obvious what will represent the full name properly.

example: my own city of Helsingborg. Given just this name i would split it down to one letter per Syllable. Hel-Sing-Borg -> HSB.
But I have never once seen anyone use this acronym. Everyone I know uses HBG.

In short, I would say its fairly easy to make a function that makes a logical acronym for any given game, but very hard to try and make one that is recognizable for a human.

If you just want to crop out some letters from a name, that would probably be a lot easier, but you'd probably want to talk to a English professor to understand what parts of names you can cut out without affecting the readability. But it is possible, and there are most likely meany publicly available studies on how we read words that you could reference.

Comment: You are right. The problem is way complex and therefore i'll just use the easy "Kick out the vowels" approach for now until i have time to find a more approriate and internationally valid solution. If i should find one, i'll post it here. Thanks for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably better advised to adopt an existing list of codes than to make up your own.  For example you could use [IATA codes](http://www.nationsonline.org/oneworld/airport_code.htm) or [zip/postal codes](http://www.geopostcodes.com/), even telephone dialling codes (find your own link for these).

Comment: The IATA Codes are a very good idea. Thanks. Though i will have plenty of Citys without airports in my List as well. I could still use IATA to at least find good shortcuts for those cities that do have an airport.